# SBJson Conflict with Facebook sdk iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, json, sdk, duplicates

I'm developing an application using SBJson framework.
now i want to add the Facebook SDK to my app but i get duplicate classes errors.

probably Facebook using some other version of SBJson source.. but the files name are the same!

i'v tried to change the classes names with the refactor tool.. but it doesn't seems to solve my problem.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook already includes the json-framework. Use what's Already included to handle your json. No need to add another seperate version of it. That's why you're getting duplicate errors.

Comment: do u have any tutorial for this? because the methods that I'm used to are not available in Facebook SDK

Comment: ...and what method's are that?

Comment: skarm thank you, i'v solved it like u said.. i used FB json librar

Comment: I installed facebook-sdk 3.0 and still having problems. I don't see any header for SBJSON, so how can I use it in my own project? I get the duplicate error if I try to add my own SBJSON (as I had before). Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem with iOS Facebook SDK version 3. Here is my question: [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12041056/duplicate-symbol-sbjson-on-ios-facebook-sdk-v-3-0)